# Background Image for UINavigationcontroller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to add background image to uinavigationcontroller. Please help me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Try this**

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

code on swift 3 and swift 4

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named:"pattern.png"),
                                                            for: .default)
```

Answer (score 0):

If You want to change navigation bar image from ViewController

1. Objective C

   ```
   [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
   ```
2. Swift

   ```
   self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named:"pi2"), for: .default)
   ```

If You want to change navigation bar image from Appdelegate

```
 1. Using Objective C

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
            [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
            return YES;
        }

 2. Using swift  


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions 
                              launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool  {
                         UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named:"img"), for:.default)
                         return true
       }
```